# JS/JQUERY TAB with history, compatibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, push, history, hashchange

Ok I have a website which have several tabs showing different things. I did a very simple thing to manage tabs:

HTML:

```
<li id="thing1" class="tab selected"></li>
<li id="thing2" class="tab"></li>
<li id="thing3" class="tab"></li>

<div id="_thing1" class="box"></div>
<div id="_thing2" class="box hidden"></div>
<div id="_thing3" class="box hidden"></div>
```

JS/JQUERY:

```
$(".tab").on('click', function() {
        $(".tab").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $(".box").addClass('hidden');
        $( '#_' + $(this).attr('id') ).removeClass('hidden');
    });
```

Everything works fine, but I'm trying to add history to my tab click, so when you click back on your browser, you go to the last tab you've visited.

I've done some research, and i'm a little confused, it seems a lot of things i need to achieve my goal are not compatible with all browser. Jquery has not implemented things related to history.

for example : on('hashchange') is not compatible with every browser it seems.

This is what I started:

```
$(".tab").on('click', function() {
history.pushState({id: $(this).attr('id')}, $(this).attr('id'), '#'+$(this).attr('id'));
}
```

So is there any way I can achieve what i want, without plugins, and easily?

Comment: have you tried browser history manipulation through JS?...

Comment: You have many plugins to choose, as [this one](http://srsgores.github.io/jquery-hash-tabs/). [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/gryzzly/xUS4D/) will help you.

Comment: Yes i did, but i stopped because i was getting confused about compatibility. I don't want to do something that i'll need to test on every browser and to worry about which version it will work on.

Comment: That's why I suggest you use a plugin, because it was already tested.

Comment: "I don't want to do something that i'll need to test on every browser and to worry about which version it will work on" .... lol better stop coding now...and then there was IE

Comment: But seriously, `hashchange` is prety well supported  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange#Browser_compatibility unless you're dealing with <IE8 or something and if that's the case, you're going to have alot more serious issues to contend with overall

Comment: Well of course i'll test it on Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari... What I meant is that I don't want to use things that might let me worry it won't work on some very dark, not very used and unknown browser version.

Comment: @ skobaljic This plugin seems very light, I'll give it a try. What i don't like with plugin is having a lot of files, this one could be added to my main js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this is what i finally did, if it could help someone:

HTML:

```
<li id="thing1" class="tab first selected"></li>
<li id="thing2" class="tab"></li>
<li id="thing3" class="tab"></li>

<div id="_thing1" class="box"></div>
<div id="_thing2" class="box hidden"></div>
<div id="_thing3" class="box hidden"></div>
```

JS:

```
var realclick = true; // prevent adding history on hashchange

$(".tab").on('click', function() {
    id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(".tab").removeClass('selected');
    $( '#' + id).addClass('selected');
    $(".box").addClass('hidden');
    $( '#_' + id ).removeClass('hidden');
    if (realclick) {
        history.pushState(null, null,  '#'+id);
    }
}); 

$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){ // triggered by browser, previous and next button
    var id ='';
    realclick = false;
    if (location.hash!='') { // if has hash
        id = $(location.hash+".tab").attr('id');
        $('#'+id).click();
    }
    else { // no hash = initial page
        id = $(".first.tab").attr('id');
        $('#'+id).click();
    }
    realclick = true;
});
```

If someone has some improvements to share, be welcome!
I need to simulate click on my tab because some of them have others events attached to them and i need to keep them.

Comment: Great solution. I may end up using this in a project I'm working on.

Comment: glad it helps! i've made some minor changes while checking your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use local storage or session storage for persist your tab history example localstorage.setItem('selectedTab','TAB_ID');

Comment: I've never heard of that, how does it work, is it safe to use, will it work on every browser, every configuration? I made a quick search and it seems you're storing data into the browser? Does every browser support this? Is this a common thing to do?

Comment: If it works as I think it works, you might have solved another problem I had!

Comment: and it seems it works with quite everything!! http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage

Comment: yeah it almost support in all html5 support browsers, but you have to make sure that your loacalstorage must be clear after use as after logout